# How static Bayesian networks are stored? Like Hugin etc

Tags: machine-learning, graphical-models

I wanted to know the standard format to store the Bayesian network structure? I came across Hugin format and others. But couldn't find out the documentation as how its been written, if I wanted to write a piece of package that writes the BN in a file which can be read by other popular Bayesian inferencing tools for Bayesian networks.

Comment: This doesn't sound like computer science to me; file formats are more a matter of software packages, not any fundamental CS concepts.

Comment: I thought since there would a standard format for storing Bayesian networks. I couldn't figure out any better stack exchange site to post about it. I felt BN is a ML tool and CS community would know more about it. I went ahead to post this query. Please delete if you feel this doesn't qualifies to be in CS stackexchange

Comment: I'm afraid not all questions have a home on the Stack Exchange network.  There might well be no better SE site to post this, but that doesn't make it on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who shares this same query. I have found a [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fgcozman/Research/InterchangeFormat/) that answers it. Further, found a [implementation](https://gitlab.com/SCoRe-Group/SABNA-Release) as well.

Comment: Please edit your question to summarize the main ideas from that link.  We discourage link-only answers.  We don't want to be just a link farm; we want to add new content.  Also, we want answers that will continue to be useful even if the link stops working.